# Can you edit all changes in a feature branch squashed as a patch file, and then apply your edits as a new commit?

Tags: git, patch

Is there a way I can edit all the changes in my feature branch all at once as a patch file, and then apply those changes as a new commit? Sometimes I need to just rename a variable that's mentioned in multiple files, or stuff like that.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what this question is trying to ask. Is the problem that you're trying condense N commits into one commit / into uncommited changes? Could you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

I add this to my `.bashrc`:

```
mainBranch="origin/master"

apply-patch() {
    _cbr=`git rev-parse HEAD`
    git stash --include-untracked
    git reset --hard `git merge-base origin/$mainBranch HEAD`
    git apply changes.patch 
    git reset $_cbr
}


make-patch() {
    git diff `git merge-base origin/$mainBranch HEAD` >changes.patch
}
```

Then I create the patch using `make-patch`, then I edit the `changes.patch` with Notepad++, and then when I type `apply-patch`. Afterwards, the changes should appear as uncommitted changes.

Comment: Why not simply a `git reset --soft whatever-parent-commit`, followed by commit?